# JSONB - update array value by index

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How to update JSON(B) array value by index? And also to retrieve the index of each value in JSONB array?

There is ServiceStack ORMLite model:

```
  public class Page
  {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [PgSqlJsonB]
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
  }
```

For example, how to update the second item in Widgets list?

Here is an example of how to do select array indexes and update array value by index in raw Postgres SQL: 
[How to update objects inside JSONB](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-update-objects-inside-jsonb-arrays-with-postgresql-5c4e03be256a/)

The idea is to select array indexes with AutoQuery and update particular JSONB array value knowing it's index in database array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OrmLite complex Types like `List<Widget>` are blobbed, so if you change the value in C# and save it, it will serialize the entire `Widgets` property to JSON and update the entire field.

If you want to use PostgreSQL native functions to manipulate the column contents in a server side query you'd need to use the [Custom SQL APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-insert-and-updates), e.g:

```
db.Execute("UPDATE page SET widgets = jsonb_set(widgets, ...) WHERE id = @id", 
    new { id });
```

Comment: Thanks Demis, that's exactly what was needed to update.
How would you also suggest to add an ordinary index of JSONB arrays to select statement? An example of SQL: https://cdn-media-1.freecodecamp.org/images/KoTlVXRd73a57XhyrIfVj0QnZfqRK8KguWoZ

Comment: @Zelid if it's returning a single JSON string field you can use `db.SqlScalar<string>(sql)`